# pass the value of variable outside the main method

Tags: java

I want to write getMethod which return value of variable text from main method. I wrote something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; // scanner
import java.io.FileReader;

public class MovieReader {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/krystian/Desktop/filmDateBaseProject/movies.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String text = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            text+= line +"\n";
            line=reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

I have this error:

> MovieReader.java:21: error: illegal start of expression public String getText()

If I write my method outside main method but in the `MovieReader` class I have this error:

> MovieReader.java:27: error: cannot find symbol of `my` variable.

Comment: You can't define a method (`getText`) inside of another method (`main`)

Comment: The point is whats the use case? where are you trying to use that variable? In another method of same class? In different class? In different package?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access local variables outside the method they're declared in. Ever.

You can make `text` not a local variable. For example, you could make it a static field in MovieReader:

```
public class MovieReader {

    private static String text;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/krystian/Desktop/filmDateBaseProject/movies.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        text = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            text+= line +"\n";
            line=reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    }

    public static String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have problem which this solution because in the other file I've created new object "read" and then if I'm trying to print this method using 'System.out.println(read.getText());' System display null

Comment: @krychuq maybe you should post your actual code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

System.out.println(MovieReader.getText());

This way you are assessing the static method in the last answer

Answer (score 0):

Another answer would be to change the last answer getText method to

```
public String getText()
{
    return MovieReader.text;
}
```

and access it with

System.out.println(read.getText());

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could make the String text 
a public static like in the code below

```
public static String text = "";

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{   
    FileReader file = new FileReader("movie.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        MovieReader.text += line + "\n";
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    reader.close();
}
```

You could access the text variable without a get method by

System.out.println(MovieReader.text);

You don't have to instantiate(make an object) to use static variables or static methods. You just reference what class they are in. (eg MovieReader)